# bash.bashrc not loading when doing a su to another user on ubuntu 19

Tags: bash, ubuntu, bashrc

When I switch to another user using **su myuser** it doesnt load any bashrc it seems.

As my command line only has the **$** symbol as I want it to have the username in the command line like how when I login as root.

I know I can just copy my root's .bashrc file, but I want to have a default .bashrc so when I do a su to another user it will auto load a default bashrc without having me to copy a .bashrc file to every /home/ user on my server.

What file should I really be editing? I plan to just copy my root's bashrc file to it as I have it customized already.

Answer (score 0):

According the the bash manual, there is no global file for bash when not run as a login shell, just `/etc/profile` for for login shells and `/etc/inputrc` for readline.

If you copied root's `.bashrc`, you should verify that the target user has permission to read the file.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "regular shells"... Bash's startup files are tied on whether the shell is interactive or not, and login shell or not. For non-login interactive shells there's `/etc/bash.bashrc` that corresponds to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I mean non login shells.

Comment: what is non-login shells? are they different when i do a su to the user?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ did you read the bash manual?